# Number of failures following the $(k-1)^{th}$ success and preceeding the $k^{th}$ success?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider a sequence of Bernoulli trials with a constant probability $p$ of success in a single trial. Let $X_k$ denote the number of failures following the $(k-1)^\text{th}$ success and preceding the $k^\text{th}$ success. Find $P(X_k=i)$

**Attempt**: $X_k=i$ denotes the following event:

$S~|~F \cdots F ~~ \text{(i times)}~|~S$

Where the $1$st $S$ represents the $(k-1)$th success and the last $S$ represents the $k$th success.

$P(X_k=i) = [ P \big(\text{  $(k-1)$th Success at $(k-1)$th trial} \big) + P\big(\text{  $(k-1)$th Success at $(k)$th trial} \big) + \cdots] \times \dfrac{1}{(1-p)^i} \times p$

$=[p^{k-1} + ~^{k-1}C_{k-2}~p^{k-2} (1-p)\times p + ~^{k}C_{k-2}~p^{k-2} (1-p)^2\times p+ ~^{k+1}C_{k-2}~p^{k-2} (1-p)^3\times p + \cdots] \times \dfrac {p}{(1-p)^i}$

$=\dfrac {p}{(1-p)^i}\times \sum_{r=0}^{n} ~^{k-2+r}C_{k-2}~~p^{k-1}~~(1-p)^r  $

$=\dfrac {p^k}{(1-p)^i}\times \sum_{r=0}^{n} ~^{k-2+r}C_{k-2}~~~(1-p)^r  $

$=\dfrac {p^k}{(1-p)^i}\times \sum_{r=0}^{n} ~^{k-2+r}C_r~~~(1-p)^r  $

Is this correct? Can this expression be simplified further?

Thanks a lot  for reading through.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to work out the probability of reaching $k - 1$ successes in some number of steps to solve this question. The events $\{(k - 1) \text{ successes are observed in }\ s \text{ trials}\}$ is independent from the event $\{X_k = i\}$ because each trial has fixed probability $p$ of success, regardless of the prior number of successes. To see why this implies that we can ignore the number of steps to $k-1$ successes, we have

$$P(X_k = i \mid k-1 \text{ successes in } s \text{ trials}) = \frac{P(X_k = i \cap k-1 \text{ successes in } s \text{ trials})}{P(k-1 \text{ successes in } s \text{ trials})} = \frac{P(X_k = i)P(k-1 \text{ successes in } s \text{ trials})}{P(k-1 \text{ successes in } s \text{ trials})} = P(X_k = i).$$

$X_k$ is just the number of trials until we see a success, regardless of how many trials and successes have been seen before. $X_k$ follows the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with
$$P(X_k = i) = p(1-p)^{i}$$
for $i = 0, 1, \dots$.